# jQuery conflict between jQuery cycle and nicescroll

Tags: jquery, conflict

I have a jQuery conflict that I was unable to fix for few days!

Here is my jQuery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/chili-1.7.pack.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.cycle.all.js"></script>

<script src="js/jquery.nicescroll.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(

    function(){ 
    jQuery(".content").niceScroll({cursorcolor:"#00F"});
    }

);

$(function(){
    $('#cycle-slideshow').cycle({
        fx:      'fade',
        timeout:  0,
        pager:   '#cycle-nav',
        //speed:  'slow',
        //timeout: 6000,
        slideExpr: 'li',
        pagerAnchorBuilder: pagerFactory
    });

    function pagerFactory(idx, slide) {
        var s = idx > 30 ? ' style="display:none"' : '';
        return '<li'+s+'><a href="#">'+(idx+1)+'</a></li>';
    };
});
</script>
```

The nicescroll works fine, but the jquery cycle doesn't!

Please help

Comment: You are including 2 versions of jQuery, which is always a recipe for a   headache. Also, you're using `noConflict()`. If the plugin isn't in a closure and relies on the `$` variable, you could have issues there. Check the console for errors.

Answer (score 0):

You should write either one of the following line

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```